# Why my pc keeps freezing on mobo logo screen or anywhere when booting?

Tags: boot, live-usb, freeze

"Ubuntu is fun" they said. Far from it when you try to uninstall not working games. I cant boot my pc anymore, no from usb, no live boot repair tool, nothing. It freezes everytime i try anything (I.E atm it's frozen to screen where i can gonto bios).

Cant tell any more details because... Well... IT FREEZES so i cant get any reports what this pc have eaten.

Question is: HOW I CAN REINSTALL UBUNTU WHEN PC FREEZES before anything starts?

Last time i got SOME INFO it said something about acpi bios error and ae_already_exists and something about hub port not found.

I got grub open ONCE but it froze

E: Now i got something:
[ 0.229343] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PCI0.GPP7._PRW], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20220331/dswload2-326)
[ 0.229354] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20220331/psobject-220)
[ 3.003.491] hub 8-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)

Comment: Based on what you have written above I'd say that `Ubuntu isn't involved`. Your PC hardware is toast in some way. It has to work to get anything else going.

Comment: You've provided so few details I doubt anyone here can help either, ie. you've made no mention of what Ubuntu product, release & ISO you're trying to boot, nor what validation you made on that ISO or write to installation media (ie. *USB thumb-drive you're booting from*).  I'd boot into the machine's uEFI/BIOS/firmware & perform diagnostics  (RAM etc tests) as what you describe would mostly be as I read it *user-procedural* error (*inc. inappropriate ISO for your hardware*) related OR hardware issues.

Comment: Huomasin suomalaisen vastaajan, joten kirjoitan ensin suomeksi/noticed one answer was from finnish guy so i try to refrace in finnish;  Eli kone jäätyy jo emolevy logoon tai kun yritän bootata tikun kautta. Eli mikään ei ehdi edes käynnistyä. Edes asennustikku. Jos yritän avata grubia, edes emon logo ei tule.

Comment: Note: this freezing problem occured when i was installing my new setup from scratch. Thats why i try to learn why it even happens. Like i mentioned in first post, it worked fine a week ago.

Comment: sorry. desktop Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy